# Uniswap V3 uses business source license BUSL-1.1, why doesn't more project use such?

Tags: uniswap

Unlike the MIT license, this may limit the usage of the code for other projects for some time. Are there any benefits to use the MIT license than this?

Answer (score 3):

The use of a BSL will likely become increasingly popular among blockchain companies that want to generate an additional moat around their product (a moat is a feature or aspect of the business that improves customer retention.) BSL thus limits direct competition and forking for a few years, which is still much more permissive than patents (looked down upon in web3), while allowing for educational code use. Also, a BSL "licensor can also make an Additional Use Grant allowing limited production use."

I hope this helps!

Source: https://mariadb.com/bsl-faq-adopting/#whatis